# Is a sense to migrate from .NET framework to .NET CORE

Tags: .net

Is it sensible to migrate from an older .Net Framework to .Net Core to support established applications.

Or to update now to newest .Net Framework 4.x, and wait until MS introduces a their new platform .Net 5.0

Could you advise? No Cross-Platform needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not require any of the features specific to .Net Core, and it sounds like you do not, then you should stay with the latest release of the .Net Framework (currently 4.8).  MS currently plans to release .Net 5.0 in November of 2020 which is supposed to be the path forward at that time. So in a year you will want to look at this issue again and likely upgrade to .Net 5 at that time.